# optimization of a seven do cycle

Tags: performance, algorithm, math, fortran, fortran90

I have 3 array and I have to do this summation

[image: A(i,j,k,l,m)=sum_{rs}B(k,l,r,s,m)*P(i,j,r,s,m)]

The implemented code is

```
do i=1,320
  do j=1,320
    do k=1,10
     do l=1,10
      do m=1,10
       do r=1,10
        do s=1,10
          sum=sum+B(k,l,r,s,m)*P(i,j,r,s,m)
        end do
       end do
       A(i,j,k,l,m)=sum
     end do 
    end do 
   end do 
 end do
end do
```

It takes 1 day to execute the code.
Is there a way to optimize it?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried defining the dimensions in increasing element order? In fortran the leftmost index varries faster because arrays are stored in column major order.

Comment: Beware : you should reset sum to 0 after `do m=1,10`.

Comment: Which compiler do you use and which (optimization) flags?

Comment: I use ifort as compiler, and i putted sum=0.d0 after the m do cycle, but i forgot to write it here.

Comment: I do not code in fortran but what about parallelism? 10 240 000 000 iterations take its time to compute but all is parallel-is-able directly without linear part so the time should be divided by number of CPU's used. also gfx computation could help more (like CUDA or GLSL) ... I think you could code this to DLL in C++ and port to fortran if fortran cant go parallel... also be aware of cache sizes of your platform you are using huge amount of data so if not coded properly then the parallel or cache speed up goes away

Comment: I know that this problem can be avoided with parallelism, and fortran allow it. But i'm not able to do it straightaway (I should first study it).

Comment: ifort has a `-parallel` compile option; see https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/automatic-parallelization-with-intel-compilers.  It could be done explicitly with Fortran & OpenMP as a reduction operation.

Comment: The two innermost loops are performing a dot product, aren't they ? By rearranging the indexing scheme, you can probably make them contiguous and perform a single loop on 100 element pairs. This should allow efficient vectorization by the compiler by enabling SSE instructions. Alternatively, consider using an efficient (parallelized) BLAS dot product.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The trick in these things is to look for common patterns and use existing efficient routines to speed them up.

M.S.B is, as usual, completely right that just flipping your indices will give you substantial speedup, although intel's fortran compiler with high optimization will already give you some of that benefit.

But let's peel off the `m` index for a second (which is easy to do as, as MSB has pointed out, that's the slowest-moving index) and just look at the multiplication:

> A<sub>i,j,k,l</sub> = ∑ B<sub>k,l,r,s</sub> × P<sub>i,j,r,s</sub> 
>   A<sub>i,j,k,l</sub> = ∑ P<sub>i,j,r,s</sub> × B<sub>k,l,r,s</sub>

reshaping the arrays:

> A<sub>ij,kl</sub> = ∑ P<sub>ij,rs</sub> × B<sub>kl,rs</sub> 
>   A<sub>ij,kl</sub> = ∑ P<sub>ij,rs</sub> × B<sup>T</sup><sub>rs,kl</sub> 
>   A = P × B<sup>T</sup>

where we now have matrix multiplication, for which very efficient routines exist.  So if we reshape the P and B matrices, and transpose B, we can do a simple matrix multiplication and reshape the result; and this reshape won't even necessarily require any copies in this case.  So changing something like this:

```
program testpsum
implicit none

integer, dimension(10,10,10,10,10) :: B
integer, dimension(32,32,10,10,10) :: P
integer, dimension(32,32,10,10,10) :: A
integer :: psum
integer :: i, j, k, l, m, r, s

B = 1
P = 2

do i=1,32
  do j=1,32
    do k=1,10
     do l=1,10
      do m=1,10
       do r=1,10
        do s=1,10
          psum=psum+B(k,l,r,s,m)*P(i,j,r,s,m)
        end do
       end do
       A(i,j,k,l,m)=psum
       psum = 0
     end do
    end do
   end do
 end do
end do

print *,minval(A), maxval(A)

end program testpsum
```

To this:

```
program testmatmult
implicit none

integer, dimension(10,10,10,10,10) :: B
integer, dimension(32,32,10,10,10) :: P
integer, dimension(10*10,10*10) :: Bmt
integer, dimension(32*32,10*10) :: Pm
integer, dimension(32,32,10,10,10) :: A
integer :: m

B = 1
P = 2

do m=1,10
    Pm  = reshape(P(:,:,:,:,m),[32*32,10*10])
    Bmt = transpose(reshape(B(:,:,:,:,m),[10*10,10*10]))
    A(:,:,:,:,m) = reshape(matmul(Pm,Bmt),[32,32,10,10])
end do

print *,minval(A), maxval(A)

end program testmatmult
```

Gives timings of:

```
$ time ./psum
         200         200

real    0m2.239s
user    0m1.197s
sys 0m0.008s

$ time ./matmult
         200         200

real    0m0.064s
user    0m0.027s
sys 0m0.008s
```

when compiled with `ifort -O3 -xhost -mkl` so we can use the fast intel MKL libraries.
It gets even faster when you don't create that `Pm` temporary and just do the reshape in the matmult call, and faster still (for large matrices) if you use `-mkl=parallel` for threaded routines.  If you don't also have MKL you can just link to some other fast LAPACK _GEMM routine.

Comment: (Note that if you use an external _GEMM routine you probably don't even have to do the transpose of B explicitly...)

Answer (score 4):

Since Fortran uses column-major ordering for the layout of multi-dimensional arrays in memory, memory access can be more efficient if you vary the left indices more quickly, i.e, inner loops for left indices.   So if you change the order of the loops so that r is inside to s, etc. the code may execute quicker.  The logic of the problem may prevent completely implementing this approach.   In some cases you might want to redefine your arrays to have a different index order.

P.S.  Do you initialize `sum` before summing?

Comment: Yes, i inizilize the sum. I'll let yu know how many time needs with this switch. Thanks