# Why the execution time is different for these fortran 95 loop methodologies?

Tags: loops, fortran, fortran95

I have a sample program to do matrix operations in fortran, which has the column major system to store matrices. Is that causing such significant difference in runtime in two array operations? If so, can someone explain why is this happening and what exactly is causing such a large runtime difference?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with GNU Fortran 4.8.4.

Code:

```
program main
implicit none

integer :: i,j
real :: start, finish
real,dimension(256,256) :: arr1

!ROW format - put 0 to main diagonal
call cpu_time(start)
do i=1,255,1
    do j=1,255,1
        arr1(i,j)=0
    end do
end do
call cpu_time(finish)

write(*,100) 'Execution time arr(i,j) in seconds= ', (finish-start)
100 format (A,f12.9)

!COLUMN format - put 1 to main diagonal
call cpu_time(start)
do j=1,255,1
    do i=1,255,1
        arr1(i,j)=1
    end do
end do
call cpu_time(finish)

write(*,100) 'Execution time arr(j,i) in seconds = ', (finish-start)

end program
```

Compile:

```
gfortran main.f95 -o main
```

Output:

```
Execution time arr(i,j) in seconds=  0.000736000
Execution time arr(j,i) in seconds =  0.000164000
```

First method is takes about 4.5 times execution time as compared to second method.

Edit: 
I am more interesting in knowing why there is such a large difference in execution time (is something odd happens at compiler or processor or memory level when we do row major ordering,  etc.)  rather than simply putting `-o3` flag or optimizing the code. This question [optimization of a seven do cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676537/optimization-of-a-seven-do-cycle/24676732#24676732) has an answer which says column major ordering is better. Why so?

Comment: My question is different than what this question addresses. Updated 'Edit' part in my question.

Comment: It's a sensible question, but it would be helpful to know what basic understanding you have, or depth of answer you would like.  Certainly you could have in-depth discussions of cache and access patterns, but equally, "array element order" may be sufficient for your needs.  I can't tell which you want/need.  At the moment your first question is "is the order important?" which suggests a very high level answer would be required, but later you say you understand that it is.

Comment: I was interested in knowing detailed reason behind this, related to cache as you said. In fact, I just updated that in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your test is strongly biased:
To see the bias, reverse the order of the two blocks that you are testing, things will start changing. For such a test, you have to:

1. write two different programs, one for each case;
2. run each program multiple times and take the average time;

You can also choose to replace the step two by a loop depending on what you are interested in.

Now, coming back to your concern, I will first mention that the question is too broad as  francescalus mentioned. To cut the story short; The computer memory is organized into an hierarchy:

1. RAM;
2. Cache (there can be many levels, for simplicity we consider one level);
3. Registers

Any level has its advantages and disadvantages:

1. The RAM can be large (giga bytes), but are very slow (about tens of nano seconds, 50 to 70).
2. The cache are not very large (few kilo to few mega bytes), faster than RAM (few nano seconds 0.5 to 2.5)
3. the register not large (only tens of bytes), very fast.

See for example [this link](http://cs.uwec.edu/~buipj/teaching/cs.352.f12/lectures/lecture_08.html) for more information. I ignored the disks that are another level of memory as well as network.

Data usually transit only from one level of memory to the next: meaning from RAM to Cache and from cache to RAM, from Cache to register and from register to cache. The CPU operates only on registers that are the faster to access. So for each operation, data are brought from the RAM to the register, and after the computation, they are brought back to the RAM. Oh no, not so fast. Let us keep it simple and say that the CPU operates on bytes (if you go deeper, you will learn the notion of words that are group of contiguous bytes and a notion of pages that is a group of contiguous words).

When you access a byte that is not already in the cache, there is a cache fault, that byte goes first from the RAM to the cache and then go to the register for your operation. When the system takes that byte from the RAM to the cache, it takes a group of contiguous bytes together. So that if the next operation is on the very neighbor, there will be no need to go to the RAM.

What happens now in you program, is that fortran stores array columnwise, meaning that in the memory elements are stored in this order:

```
a(1,1) a(2,1) a(3,1) ... a(M,1) a(1,2) a(2,2) a(3,2) ... a(M,2) ...
```

So the loop

```
do j=1,255,1
    do i=1,255,1
        arr1(i,j)=1
    end do
end do
```

is accessing elements in the order they are stored in the memory. The number of trips between the RAM and the cache is reduced to the minimum.

For the  other loop

```
do i=1,255,1
    do j=1,255,1
        arr1(i,j)=1
    end do
end do
```

You are simply not accessing the elements in the right order. For example if your cache can only hold less than a column of your matrix, it means that for any iteration of the inner loop, the system has to refill the cache. And it is not that simple, to refill the cache, the system will first copy back the data that are in the cache to the RAM if they have been modified, which is the case here. To see this, increase to matrix to the maximum size that your RAM can handle, and you will see what it means to to not follow the storage logic, the gap will increase. You can go gradually, 1000x1000, then 10000x10000, etc. When you cache can only hold a single column or less, you will get a factor close the one between the acces times of the RAM and the cahe. Remember, more than 10.

The topic of memory is the subject of many courses in computer science. I wanted to give you only what I can give quickly.

Answer (score 1):

To work on data, the CPU needs to read it from RAM into its cache. It takes amost the same amout of time to read in a single byte as it does to read in quite a lot of sequential bytes.

If your iner loop is over the non-contiguous dimension, the CPU has to read and write every singe value from and to RAM independently. If your inner loop is over the contiguous dimension, it can read a lot of values in one go, and then operate on them in its cache.